# Sublime Text 3 Python 3.5.2 can not build

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

Some of simple codes run without problem.
But I tried to run this simple code on sublime but I got this error.
I run same code from command line without a problem. I also install anaconda.

```
number1 = 23
running = True
while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer :'))
    if guess == number1:
        print ('Congrats')
        running=False
    elif guess<number1:
        print('no it is a little higher then that')
    else:
        print('no it is a little lower than that')
else:           
    print('the while loop is over')
    print('done')
```

Error message on sublime:

```
Enter an integer :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\while.py", line 4, in <module>
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer :'))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: Even though the duplicate says Sublime Text 2, the explanation and solution should still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line below, the interpreter is seeing that last line as incomplete without the newline.

Comment: No. That is not it. The duplicate explains the problem.